# Comparing two lists containing tuples to find missing values

Tags: python

I am currently having two lists of tuples in Python, like:

```
A = [(1001, 'C:\\dd\fff'), (1002, 'C:\\dd\eee')]
B = [(1001, 'C:\\dd\fff'), (1002, 'C:\\dd\eee'), (1003, 'C:\\dd\ggg')]
```

The resultant list should only contain **values from list `B` which are not in list `A`.**

Tried with `(set(A) - set(B))`, but due to second parameter as file path it's not providing correct result. Can someone please point out how to achieve this using Python?

Comment: `Resultant list should only contain values from list B which are not in list A.` the entire tuple? Or the first value in the tuple?

Comment: I guess what you want is `set(B) - set(A)`, note that the order of the operands matters as set difference is not conmutative

Comment: @yatu Entire tuple

Comment: @Tomerikoo, it is similar but in my tuple it contains file names in second value of tuple, coz of which set is not getting compared.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do... tuples are hashable therefore it will work exactly the same...

Comment: Please note **the order** of subtraction... You need `set(B) - set(A)` not the other way around

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
list(set(B) - set(A))
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo this don't work , as other tuple has file path in it

Comment: @sammy I really don't understand what that means... Please edit your question with your current and expected output so we can understand what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about order you might use `set` based solution, otherwise you can harness *list comprehension* as follows:

```
A = [(1001,'C:\\dd\fff'),(1002,'C:\\dd\eee')]
B = [(1001,'C:\\dd\fff'),(1002,'C:\\dd\eee'), (1003,'C:\\dd\ggg')]
result = [i for i in B if i not in A]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1003, 'C:\\dd\\ggg')]
```

Comment: Hi Daweo, Thanks for prompt reply, but instead of checking "i not in A" can we compare tuples first value.